# How to write a change event method in vue-monthly-picker

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am using [vue-monthly-picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-monthly-picker) to render a datepicker. How can I write a method that executes whenever I change the month?

This is my code

```
<vuemonthlypicker
    v-model="selectedMonth"
    :monthLabels=monthLabels
>
</vuemonthlypicker>
```

Answer (score 1):

if the documentation is anything to go by, my guess is

```html
<vuemonthlypicker
    v-model="selectedMonth"
    :monthLabels=monthLabels
    @selected="onSelected"
>
</vuemonthlypicker>
```

where `onSelected` is a function defined in your methods.

Answer (score 1):

You have three options. The easiest option with this library is by using the event that is described in the documentation. By putting `v-on:selected` or `@selected` in your component, you call a function with an instance of [moment](https://momentjs.com/).

```
<vuemonthlypicker
  v-model="selectedMonth"
  :monthLabels="monthLabels"
  @selected="handleSelected"
/>
```

The second option is by keeping in mind that `v-model` is actually syntactic sugar for `:value="variable" @input="(value) => variable = value"`. You can use this by defining your own function for the `@input` event, even though it isn't as clean.

```
<vuemonthlypicker
  :value="selectedMonth2"
  @input="changeSelectedMonth2"
  :monthLabels="monthLabels"
/>
```

The third option is by defining a watcher on the variable that is being changed through the `v-model`. This is somewhat cleaner when defining a function that has side-effects.

```
<vuemonthlypicker
  v-model="selectedMonth"
  :monthLabels="monthLabels"
/>
```

with:

```
watch: {
  selectedMonth(x) {
    console.log("from watcher", x);
  }
}
```

[image: Edit Vue Template]

Comment: thanks for your replay.
i get it done by :selected="handleSelected()"